# Video not displaying on iOS, other videos on same page work

Tags: ios, video

I have a video display issue on [this page](https://www.hedinger-design.com/truchef.html) of my site, **only** when viewing on iOS mobile devices.

The strange thing is that I have another video element on the same page and that one plays fine. Same format, same css, html, attributes, etc. Both videos were rendered in AE with the same settings, so codecs are also the same.

Here is the section of code containing both videos:

```
<div id="sec-04" class="project-section">
    <div class="projectvid" id="wipeAnim">
        <video preload playsinline autoplay loop muted><source src="/assets/truChef_wipeAnimation_16x9.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div id="sec-05" class="project-section">
    <div id="imgCont-05" class="projectimg"><div id="img-05" class="img"></div></div>
</div>
    
<div id="sec-06" class="project-section">
    <div class="projectvid" id="explodedAnim">
        <video preload playsinline autoplay loop muted><source src="/assets/truChef_explodedView_16x9.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:**

1. Both videos play fine in Chrome Dev tools device simulation.
2. Both videos **do not** play at all in [browserstack.com](https://live.browserstack.com)'s real cloud iPhones.
3. On my actual iPhone 6, the first video (id="wipeAnim") **is not playing**,
   the second video (id="explodedAnim") **is playing**.

Does anybody know why this first video isn't playing/showing up at all on iOS? I can't figure it out - it just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: both look fine in `ffmpeg`, but you have an unnecessarily high bitrate for those videos (7mb for a 15 sec video). I'd recommend re-encoding through [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/), which has presets for mobile compatibility. You can also take out the unnecessary audio track while you're at it.

Comment: thanks Luke. I didn't think there was going to be a problem with the video files themselves, although your advice about converting to a lower bitrate is definitely good advice in terms of mobile delivery, and I will convert those files. 

However, that still leaves the question why does one of them not display on my website when viewed on an iphone, even though the other one does play?